# IPhone library project + UIViews

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm trying to refactor some of my iphone code into a library project that can be linked to by several different applications.  I made a new iphone library project and copied over some of my classes there, but the project can't build because it doesn't know about stuff like UIView or CGRect.  I added in the UIKit, CoreGraphics, and QuartzCore frameworks, but still no go.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Check that all source code that references UIView or CGRect has the line

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

in the beginning.

Comment: wow that did it.. not sure why it wasn't required in the original application project.  thanks a lot!